# Catch error server response with @nuxtjs/auth

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js

I'm trying to catch the error response for @nuxtjs/auth but it doesn't seem to return anything but undefined.

It refuses to login if I include the user so I want to know why it's returning undefined.

CONFIG:

```
auth: {
    strategies: {
        local: {
            endpoints: {
                login: {
                    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:80/api/login',
                    method: 'post',
                    propertyName: 'token'
                },
                logout: false,
                user: {
                    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:80/api/me',
                    method: 'get',
                    propertyName: undefined
                }
            },
            tokenRequired: true,
            tokenType: 'bearer',
        }
    },
    plugins: [
        '@/plugins/auth.js'
    ]
},
```

PLUGIN:

```
export default function ({ app }) {
    app.$auth.onError((error, name, endpoint) => {
        console.error(name, error)
    });
}
```

VIEW FUNCTION:
- both handleSuccess and handleFailure returns undefined.

```
login() {
    this.toggleProcessing(0);

    let payload = {
        username: 'admin',
        password: 'admin123'
    }

    let handleSuccess = response => {
        console.log(response);
        this.toggleProcessing(0);
    }

    let handleFailure = error => {
        console.log(error);
        this.toggleProcessing(0);
    }

    this.$auth.loginWith('local', { data: payload }).then(handleSuccess).catch(handleFailure);
},
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use `e.response`

```js
async login() {
    try {
      const login = {
        username: this.username,
        password: this.password
      }
      let response = await this.$auth.loginWith('local', { data: login })
      console.log('response', response)
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('Error Response', e.response)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I fell into the same problem and after spending some time i found out a very good way to catch the response. The solution is to use the axios interceptor. Just replace your plugin file code with the following

```
export default function ({$axios, $auth}){

  $axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
    // Do something with response data

    return response;
  }, function (error) {
    // Do something with response error

    return Promise.reject(error);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure initially what might be wrong here because I can't see the complete `nuxt.config.js` and your full component but here are a few things to check:

- `@nuxtjs/axios` is installed
- Both `axios` and `auth` modules are registered in the `modules` section of `nuxt.config.js`: 
  `modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/auth'
  ]`
- Also, ensure the `middleware` property for `auth` is set in the component/page component.

Ensure you're following the documentation on this page: https://auth.nuxtjs.org/getting-starterd/setup

Answer (score 0):

Ive been using try -> this.$auth.loginWith to catch error server response with @nuxtjs/auth.

```
login() {
  const data = { form };
  try {
    this.$auth
      .loginWith("local", { data: data })
      .then(api => { 
        // response
        this.response.success = "Succes"; 
      })
      .catch(errors => {
        this.response.error = "Wrong username/password";
      });
  } catch (e) {
    this.response.error = e.message;
  }
},
```

Specify the token field in the nuxt.config

```
strategies: {
  local: {
    endpoints: {
      login: { // loginWith
        url: "auth/login",
        method: "post",
        propertyName: "data.token" // token field
      }, 
      user: { // get user data
        url: "auth/user",
        method: "get",
        propertyName: "data.user"
      },
    }
  }
},

modules: ["@nuxtjs/axios", "@nuxtjs/auth"],
```